# Is there an automatic way to generate a rollback script when inserting data with LINQ2SQL?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linq-to-sql, rollback

Let's assume we have a bunch of LINQ2SQL `InsertOnSubmit` statements against a given `DataContext`. If the `SubmitChanges` call is successful, is there any way to automatically generate a list of SQL commands (or even LINQ2SQL statements) that could **undo** everything that was submitted at a later time? It's like executing a rollback even though everything worked as expected.

Note: The destination database will either be Oracle or SQL Server, so if there is specific functionality for both databases that will achieve this, I'm happy to use that as well.

**Clarification:**
I do not want the "rollback" to happen automatically as soon as the inserts have succesfully completed. I want to have the ability to "undo" the INSERT statements via DELETE (or some other means) up to 24 hours (for example) after the original program finished inserting data. We can ignore any possible referential integrity issues that may come up.

Assume a Table A with two columns: `Id` (autogenerated unique id) and `Value` (string)

If the LINQ2SQL code performs two inserts

```
 INSERT INTO Table A VALUES('a') // Creates new row with Id = 1
 INSERT INTO Table A VALUES('z') // Creates new row with Id = 2

<< time passes>>
```

At some point later I would want to be able "undo" this by executing

```
 DELETE FROM A Where Id = 1
 DELETE FROM A Where Id = 2
```

or something similar. I want to be able to generate the `DELETE` statements to match the `INSERT` ones. Or use some functionality that would let me capture a transaction and perform a rollback later.

We cannot just 'reset the database' to a certain point in time either as other changes not initiated by our program could have taken place since.

Comment: When you say "...at a later point in time..." are you thinking of seconds, years or something in-between? 
Would the delete be triggered from the same session of the calling application, or potentially from other sessions (or other applications)? A bit more context might be helpful.

Comment: I am thinking of "minutes to hours" as a "later point in time". It would not be triggered from the same context of the calling application, or even the same session. It would be executed from a different program (or even through some IDE like Management Studio if SQL undo code was available).

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer.

Comment: Well there were no answers, unfortunately, for the situation I was describing. I did give you an upvote for learning something new :)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite easy to do this, because you can pass in a `SqlConnection` into the LINQ to SQL `DataContext` on construction. Just run this connection in a transaction and roll that transaction back as soon as you're done.

Here's an example:

```
string output;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your conn.string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.StartTransaction())
    {
        using (var context = new YourDataContext(connection))
        {
            // This next line is needed in .NET 3.5.
            context.Transaction = transaction;

            var writer = new StringWriter();
            context.Log = writer;

            // *** Do your stuff here ***

            context.SubmitChanges();

            output = writer.ToString();
        }

        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry; I wasn't clear enough in the question. I don't want to rollback the transaction right away (necessarily). I want to have the SQL (or something) that I could run later in the future that would delete all the inserts that happened. (Let's assume we don't have to worry about referential integrity).

Comment: That would generate the SQL to actually do the INSERTs :) I am looking to generate the code that would perform the DELETE statements.

Comment: I did learn something with your answer :) I hadn't realise you could log the statements executed with a DataContext so I appreciate your response regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I am always required to provide a RollBack script to our QA team for testing before any change script can be executed in PROD.

Example: Files are sent externally with a bunch of mappings between us, the recipient and other third parties. One of these third parties wants to change, on an agreed date, the mappings between the three of us.

Exec script would maybe update some exisiting, delete some now redundant and insert some new records - scope_identity used in subsequent relational setup etc etc.

If, for some reason, after we have all executed our changes and the file transport is fired up, just like in UAT, we see some errors not encountered in UAT, we might multilaterally make the decision to roll back the changes. Hence the roll back script.

SQL has this info when you BEGIN TRAN until you COMMIT TRAN or ROLLBACK TRAN. I guess your question is the same as mine - can you output that info as a script.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this?

Maybe you should explore the flashback possibilities of Oracle. It makes it possible to travel back in time.

It makes it possible to reset the content of a table or a database to how it once was at a specific moment in time (or at a specific system change number).

See: http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/availability/htdocs/Flashback_Overview.htm

Comment: I need this because even though a transfer between two systems may go exactly as planned, someone on one side may still want to be able to "undo" the migration afterwards. Probably within 24 hours.

Comment: We wouldn't want to reset the table/database to a specific moment in time as other operations may have happened since then. We would only want to delete our own inserts.

Comment: Can't you add an extra column to the table and fill it with some kind of "transfer job" number? If someone wants to "undo" a "transfer job" you simply delete all the rows with that specific job number.

Comment: Interesting idea; however we don't own the schema to the other database and there would be multiple tables involved. Something to consider, but the chances of approval for that seem slim.

Comment: I think it is the most simple solution and less error-prone. Adding new features often means that the schema has to change. Another solution is the use of a new set of tables for data that needs to be approved by "the other side". Once it is approved, you transfer this data to the production tables.